# v-date-picker not opening on specified date

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

I'm working in a vue.js application with vuetify and I'm trying to get a v-date-picker to work. The problem is that it won't open on the date specified in the v-model. For example, I set the specified date to '2020-02-15' and bind it to the v-model, but it opens on January 2020. The user has to scroll to February to see the selected date.

Here's a jsfiddle to show this problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/ozwpd5a9/

template:

```
<div id='app'>
  <v-date-picker v-model='selectedDate'></v-date-picker>
</div>
```

script:

```
const td = new Date();
const start = new Date(2018, td.getMonth() + 1, 13);
const end = new Date(2018, 9, 13);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      // Data used by the date picker
      mode: 'single',
      selectedDate: '2020-02-15',
                availableDates: { start, end }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass it as a `Date` type.

```
selectedDate: new Date('2020-02-15')
```

[Reference](https://docs.vcalendar.io/api/datepicker.html)